# BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
    providers: [
         BlocProvider<TripDetailBloc>(create: (BuildContext context) => TripDetailBloc()),
         BlocProvider<PopUpBloc>(create: (BuildContext context) => PopUpBloc()),
               ],
    child: Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          BlocProvider.of<TripDetailBloc>(context).add(AddTripDetailPannelEvent());
        },
      ),
      appBar: appbar(),
      body: pannel(),
    )
    );
  }
```

**The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:**

- BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type
  TripDetailBloc.
- No ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to
  BlocProvider.of`<TripDetailBloc>()`.
- This can happen if the context you used comes from a widget above the
  BlocProvider.
- he context used was: TripDetailPage(dependencies: [MediaQuery],
  state: _TripDetailPageState#d4ab3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
  return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<TripDetailBloc>(create: (BuildContext context) => TripDetailBloc()),
        BlocProvider<PopUpBloc>(create: (BuildContext context) => PopUpBloc()),
      ],
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          return Scaffold(
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () {
                BlocProvider.of<TripDetailBloc>(context).add(AddTripDetailPannelEvent());
              },
            ),
            appBar: appbar(),
            body: pannel(),
          );
        }
      )
  );
}
```

If you look closely, I have rapped your Scaffold into a widget builder.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked for me. Pretty weird though, I guess the provider does not have access to the context if you want to access directly from the child widget without creating any build method in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your scaffold in a builder widget and use that context. The context the .of(context) is using is the same of the method build(BuildContext context), that's why it doesn't find it